# Change concurrency/manage queue in running celery app

Tags: python, celery

I am using celery 5 to manage some external tasks within a fast API app.
I started celery with one worker and 8 concurrent jobs:

`celery worker --app=app.worker.celery --concurrency=8 --loglevel=info --logfile=logs/celery.log`

I want to be able to change the concurrency from the fast API app. I don't know if this is the best way of doing this or even if it is possible.
I haven't found a way to change the concurrency so I tried to add new workers, using

```py
from celery import current_app as app
cmd = ["--app=app.worker.celery", "--concurrency=8", "--loglevel=info", "--logfile=logs/celery.log", "--without-gossip" , "--detach", "-E"]
app.worker_main(cmd)
```

but this doesn't work even passing `--detach` it blocks the request.

Is there another/better way of doing this?

EDIT:

after looking how [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/ce5f0de7b25bc42ef9fb909340ba9fe9c8f903f0/flower/api/control.py#L160) 1.0.1 does this I was able to track the right API.
Solved:

```py
from celery import current_app as app
response = app.control.pool_grow(
            n=4, reply=True, destination=[worker_name])
```

Comment: Did you test whether you can run Celery worker with those arguments in the command line (not from Python script)? Remove the `--logfile=logs/celery.log` so that you can see any eventual errors from worker startup.

Comment: @DejanLekic, yes, via CMD it works, `--detach` works too, it creates a background process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flower](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) allows to grow and shrink the pool ([here](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/ce5f0de7b25bc42ef9fb909340ba9fe9c8f903f0/flower/api/control.py#L160) the flower implementation)

```py
from celery import current_app as app
n = 10 # increase the pool size
worker_name = "my_worker"
response = app.control.pool_grow(
            n=n, reply=True, destination=[worker_name])
```

The only problem is that it does not have an option to get the pool size after one changes it

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. @Rafael, you get the pool information from the `stats` inspect command.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own autoscaler by subclassing `celery.worker.autoscale.AutoScaler` and setting [`worker_autoscaler`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-worker_autoscaler) .  Your autoscaler could, for example, monitor a database record and when that changes, scales up.

Comment: hum, this might be a good option. I will try. I found that flower has an API
`api/worker/pool/grow/` that can increase the number of task in one worker.. trying to find how to call this using celery directly